# Teams Bot on BotFramework with different entra id

Tags: teams-toolkit

I had this bot for months now but I decided to create a new environment and that created a new entry on BotFramework with a new Entra Id, but now everytime I run TeamsFx it just says

> "(√) Done: Used existing Microsoft Entra application with client id xxxxxxxx."

I can't choose the Entra application anymore, I even deleted the newest one on Azure but it keeps using it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

please remove the BOT_ID and BOT_PASSWORD in your env and env.user file, and Teamsfx will create a new entra id for you.

Comment: Hi! In this case I want to use the older one, but teamsfx always chooses the newest one, even after I deleted every registry of it on Azure (atleast every registry that I know of). I tried setting BOT_ID and BOT_PASSWORD for the older one but it just gets replaced.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Teamsfx?

Also I'm not sure if I understand correctly, do you mean that:
1. You have 2 pairs of BOT_ID and BOT_PASSWORD, an older pair and a new pair.
2. You have 2 envs, one using older pair one using newer pair.
3. You want to use the older pair, but the message "(√) Done: Used existing Microsoft Entra application with client id xxxxxxxx." shows it's using the newer BOT_ID.

If that's the case, maybe you are using the wrong env. If not, please help clarify, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I was using the latest version and you got it right. I have 2 pairs of ID/PASSWORD and I want to use the older pair. They both works if I just run without teamsfx (which means both exists) but If I run with teamsfx, it overwrites ANY env I have with the newest ID/PASSWORD, this means I can't update the older anymore.
After hours trying, what I ended up doing to resolve my problem, was running teamsfx on a web dev tool (sets up a proxy) to catch all requests from teamsfx, then I did all of them manually with the older tokens to update what I needed. Thanks for the help!